# Front end theme customization Magento 2

Tags: magento2, theme, design

I want to change the front end design of my Magento store. I have created new theme from the parent theme LUMA. I also have created html pages and css files as per my desired design. Now i want to integrate my html design to Magento store. I am a newbie to Magento. So guys please help me with design integration. 
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This could probably be a comment, rather than an answer, but I don't have the reputation to post a comment.

I found the easiest way to get familiar with themeing and the layout engine for Magento is to start with a copy the Blank or Luma themes, and customize them. This will give you an idea of the basic templates that need to exists as well as the theme registration and xml layout files.